Using socket-io (backend) inside AWS EC2 Container under path "/api" and ngx-socket-io (client side front-end)
I've been implementing websockets to comunnincate frontend and backend.
Backend is NodeJS (Socket-io library V4.0.0)
Frontend is Angular ( ngx-socket-io library V4.1.0).
The implementation works fine when running in localhost (http://localhost:port).
Frontend connects to socket adding default path to url localhost:port/socket.io
The problem happens when the application is deployed on Amazon ECS (docker containers) because it's configured to use same url for both front and back.
If path starts with "/api" it points to backend (example: https://mydns.com/api/login). Otherwise, any other route without starting with /api will point to the frontend routes.
On this "production stage" frontend client isn't getting socket messages from server.
I can see in browsers console that the frontend socket library its making 4 requests:
First one response is OK
Second one displays an error: "Invalid namespace".
Third and fourth are random strings.
**Node socket.io implementation: **
`.
const params = {
cors: {
origin: '*',
}
}
const io = require('socket.io')(server, params);
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New connection from ' + socket.request.connection.remoteAddress);
  
      socket.on('userInit', (data)=>{
        console.log("USER LOGGED IN: " + data,);
        io.emit("userLoggedIn", data)
      })
    });
    
io.on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log('User disconnected');
});

`
Angular ngx-socket-io implementation:
`.
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketWebServiceService extends Socket {
  constructor() {
    super({ 
       url:  environment.apiUrl,  
       options: environment.production?{ path: "/api/socket.io"}:{}
    });
   }

`
As I could see, ngx-soket-io wont use the full apiUrl (it removes the "/api") that's why in production build I add the param "path" to "/api/socket.io" when initializing websocket.
I know it's a difficult question, sorry about that.
Thanks in advance.
Im expecting to messages sent by server socket work the same as when I run it in local stage.
